# Why inherit the box sizing css reset than apply it directly to all elements?

Tags: html, css, border

I've seen this box-sizing CSS reset trick in a tutorial and I've read a little about it but I don't see why it's done in this way than just applied to the universal selector. For instance, why this way:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

instead of just setting the border-box property on the second section and removing the html selector, in theory it should do the same thing if I understand it right. Every selector and pseudo element would have the border-box property applied to it.

Comment: Does this help? https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/

Comment: I had read that but I just wanted a more laymans explanation for what was happening there? sorry but I didn't understand it. Why specifically is inherit working but the universal selector approach doesn't? In theory I think it should but I don't see why it's not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

is saying is that html element has box-sizing: border-box and that all elements are then going to inherit the box-sizing of their parent.

So, if you like 'to begin with' every element inherits box-sizing from html's setting because no one has told it anything different.

But supposing you have somewhere

```
.mydiv {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

with HTML

```
<div class="mydiv">
  <header>some text...
  </header>
</div>
```

what do you expect the box-sizing of the header element to be?

What setting the inherits above is saying is 'I expect header to inherit its box-sizing from its parent' and that is content-box.

If we'd had everything set to border-box at the start it would not be inheriting, it would use what it had been set at, border-box.

Comment: I guess if you set everything to border-box at the start, you could still override it by applying a content-box class as needed, so that would solve that issue.

Comment: Yes, you could always explicitly set it for any one element, but its child elements would be set at border-box still if that was what you had set * at. So, you can either have a universal 'inherit' as in the question or a universal <some other setting> and just remember the effect on child elements differs.